# How do i compute this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions, sturm-liouville

$$ y''(x) - \frac{B^2}{\cosh^2(Bx)}y(x)= Ay(x) $$

I know that can be solved analytically, but what method can I use?

Comment: Mathematica finds a solution for $A=B=1$ in terms of the hypergeometric function 2F1.

Comment: Why do you keep two separate $y$ terms ?

Comment: @Yves Because i want to see it as a Schrödinger equation

Comment: This equation is like Schroedinger equation with a potential $V(x)= B^2 \mbox{sech}^2x$ Potential, when $A<0$ it will correspond to scattering from this bell shape potential with energy=-A. You may see Practical Quantum Mechanics by S.  Flugge, Problem no. 39. This potential wellknown as Scarf II, Eckart and Soliton potential. You may search with these key words.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $B\neq0$ for the key case:

Hint:

$y''(x)-\dfrac{B^2}{\cosh^2(Bx)}y(x)=Ay(x)$

Let $r=\cosh(Bx)$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dx}=B\sinh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(B\sinh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)=B\sinh(Bx)\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)+B^2\cosh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}=B\sinh(Bx)\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dr}\right)\dfrac{dr}{dx}+B^2\cosh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}=B\sinh(Bx)\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}B\sinh(Bx)+B^2\cosh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}=B^2\sinh^2(Bx)\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+B^2\cosh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}$

$\therefore B^2\sinh^2(Bx)\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+B^2\cosh(Bx)\dfrac{dy}{dr}-\dfrac{B^2}{\cosh^2(Bx)}y=Ay$

$B^2(r^2-1)\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}+B^2r\dfrac{dy}{dr}-\left(A+\dfrac{B^2}{r^2}\right)y=0$

Let $s=r^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dr}=\dfrac{dy}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dr}=2r\dfrac{dy}{ds}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}=\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(2r\dfrac{dy}{ds}\right)=2r\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{dy}{ds}\right)+2\dfrac{dy}{ds}=2r\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(\dfrac{dy}{ds}\right)\dfrac{ds}{dr}+2\dfrac{dy}{ds}=2r\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}2r+2\dfrac{dy}{ds}=4r^2\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{ds}$

$\therefore B^2(r^2-1)\left(4r^2\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{ds}\right)+2B^2r^2\dfrac{dy}{ds}-\left(A+\dfrac{B^2}{r^2}\right)y=0$

$4B^2r^2(r^2-1)\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}+2B^2(2r^2-1)\dfrac{dy}{ds}-\left(A+\dfrac{B^2}{r^2}\right)y=0$

$4B^2s(s-1)\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}+2B^2(2s-1)\dfrac{dy}{ds}-\left(A+\dfrac{B^2}{s}\right)y=0$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}+\dfrac{2s-1}{2s(s-1)}\dfrac{dy}{ds}-\left(\dfrac{A}{4B^2s(s-1)}+\dfrac{1}{4s^2(s-1)}\right)y=0$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}+\left(\dfrac{1}{2s}+\dfrac{1}{2(s-1)}\right)\dfrac{dy}{ds}-\left(\dfrac{A+B^2}{4B^2s(s-1)}-\dfrac{1}{4s^2}\right)y=0$

Let $y=s^ku$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{ds}=s^k\dfrac{du}{ds}+ks^{k-1}u$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{ds^2}=s^k\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}+ks^{k-1}\dfrac{du}{ds}+ks^{k-1}\dfrac{du}{ds}+k(k-1)s^{k-2}u=s^k\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}+2ks^{k-1}\dfrac{du}{ds}+k(k-1)s^{k-2}u$

$\therefore s^k\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}+2ks^{k-1}\dfrac{du}{ds}+k(k-1)s^{k-2}u+\left(\dfrac{1}{2s}+\dfrac{1}{2(s-1)}\right)\left(s^k\dfrac{du}{ds}+ks^{k-1}u\right)-\left(\dfrac{A+B^2}{4B^2s(s-1)}-\dfrac{1}{4s^2}\right)s^ku=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}+\dfrac{2k}{s}\dfrac{du}{ds}+\dfrac{k(k-1)}{s^2}u+\left(\dfrac{1}{2s}+\dfrac{1}{2(s-1)}\right)\dfrac{du}{ds}+\left(\dfrac{k}{2s^2}+\dfrac{k}{2s(s-1)}\right)u-\left(\dfrac{A+B^2}{4B^2s(s-1)}-\dfrac{1}{4s^2}\right)u=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}+\left(\dfrac{4k+1}{2s}+\dfrac{1}{2(s-1)}\right)\dfrac{du}{ds}+\left(\dfrac{4k^2-2k+1}{4s^2}+\dfrac{B^2(2k-1)-A}{4B^2s(s-1)}\right)u=0$

Choose $4k^2-2k+1=0$ , i.e. $k=\dfrac{1\pm i\sqrt3}{4}$ , the ODE becomes

$\dfrac{d^2u}{ds^2}+\left(\dfrac{2\pm i\sqrt3}{2s}+\dfrac{1}{2(s-1)}\right)\dfrac{du}{ds}+\dfrac{B^2(-1\pm i\sqrt3)-2A}{8B^2s(s-1)}u=0$

Which reduces to Gaussian hypergeometric equation.

Comment: The rules do not permit super-human intelligence to post here. And you even out-witted MathJax.